# How to change docker image storage directory?

Tags: image, docker, storage

I have a centos running on t2.medium instance in aws.

Then i created a EBS and Mount EBS. I have already docker installed before mounting and now I wanted to pull the docker image and use that volume. Since docker was installed on`/` and the volume i mounted is on `/data`. How can I make sure that the image I pull is used by the mounted volume.

```
dev/xvda1      8.0G  1.6G  6.5G  20% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G   17M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/xvdf        50G   53M   47G   1% /data
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the distribution and docker installation, you can set the directory that the docker daemon uses. Check out this post: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649560/how-to-change-docker-daemon-root-directory-in-centos7 This helped me